# Google Vis annotated timeline from SQL database using PHP JSON issue

Tags: php, javascript, json, postgresql, google-visualization

I am trying to create a simple annotated timeline from a PostgreSQL database using a server side PHP script to access the data from the database, then a JavaScript client side script to display the graph. Basically pretty straightforward stuff there. Now as you may guess, nothing is showing up when I visit the page.

So here is where I've gotten: When I looked at my apache log files, I can see that my PHP script is parsing correctly, and when I use the hyperlink (including all the extra goodies that my JavaScript added to properly ask PHP for what it wants from the database) I can see the response in the correct Google format. At least I think. I KINDA think that the issue may be that the response from my PHP function is actually in an incorrect syntax for the Google annotated timeline object, but I cant find enough documentation to prove that is true or not.

Here is a truncated version of what my PHP function spits out:

```
Google.visualization.Query.setResponse({version:'0.5',reqId:'0',status:'ok',table:{cols: [{id:'date',label:"date",type:'datetime'},{id:'temp',label:"temp",type:'number'}],
rows: [{c:[{v:new Date(2011,2,22,13,47,26),f:"03\/22\/2011 01:47pm"},{v:132.8,f:"133"}]},{c:[{v:new Date(2011,2,22,13,48,57),f:"03\/22\/2011 01:48pm"},{v:136.8,f:"137"}]},
       {c:[{v:new Date(2011,2,22,13,56,49),f:"03\/22\/2011 01:56pm"},{v:132.8,f:"133"}]},{c:[{v:new Date(2011,2,22,13,58,42),f:"03\/22\/2011 01:58pm"},{v:128.8,f:"129"}]},
       {c:[{v:new Date(2011,2,22,14,1,26),f:"03\/22\/2011 02:01pm"},{v:124.8,f:"125"}]},{c:[{v:new Date(2011,2,22,14,4,19),f:"03\/22\/2011 02:04pm"},{v:128.8,f:"129"}]},{c:[{v:new Date(2011,2,22,14,5,51),f:"03\/22\/2011 02:05pm"},{v:132.8,f:"133"}]},
```

And it goes on of course, but I figured I would give you an idea of what I was seeing, not put you to sleep with a complete dump.

Now I know by putting in document.write("got here"); kinda tags into my JavaScript, I can tell that the program does finish, and doesn't throw any crazy errors due to silly oversights on my part...(Opening mouth in preparation to insert foot)... However somehow from what I have read elsewhere it this query response looks mal-formatted somehow (I did change the formatting and insert spacing for readability in this post, so if you see something wrong with the spacing, it was more than likely me). I will include both my PHP and my JavaScript code at the bottom of this post. If anyone sees anything glaring that I missed, or have any insights into what could be the problem, I would really appreciate some help with this!

Thanks in advance everyone!

JavaScript **index.html**

```
<html> 
  <head> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
          <script type="text/javascript"> 
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["annotatedtimeline"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
                var query = new google.visualization.Query('/vis.php');
            query.setQuery('SELECT date,temp FROM temp1 ORDER BY date');
            query.send(function(result) {
                document.write(result.getDetailedMessage());
                  if(result.isError()) {
                  alert(result.getDetailedMessage());

            } else {

                var data = result.getDataTable();
            var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));                   
            chart.draw(data,{displayAnnotations: false});
                 }
               });
               }
            </script> 
      </head> 
    <body> 
    <div id="chart_div"></div> 
  </body> 
 </html>
```

PHP **vis.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'MC/Google/Visualization.php';

$user = 'postgres';
$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=house',$user,'');
$vis = new MC_Google_Visualization($db,'postgres');

$vis->addEntity('temp1', array(
'fields' => array(
'date' => array('field' => 'date', 'type' => 'datetime'),
'temp' => array('field' => 'temp', 'type' => 'number')
   )
));

$vis->setDefaultEntity('temp1');
$vis->handleRequest();
?>
```

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**EDIT: Functional Code Alert!**

Ok, so here is where I'm at now, this code works, but of course doesnt pull anything from my database. As you can see, the formatting is exactly the same as I was getting from the PHP function above.

**FUNCTIONAL CODE** *but not what I'm looking for*

```
<html> 
  <head> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
          <script type="text/javascript"> 
       google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["annotatedtimeline"]});
       google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
           function drawChart() {
                  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable( 
                  { 
                cols: [{id:'date',label: 'date', type: 'datetime'}, 
                       {id:'level',label: 'level', type: 'number'}], 
                rows: [ 
                       {c:[{v: new Date(2011,2,24,6,52,26),f:"03\/24\/2011 06:52am"}, {v:91.4,f:"91"} ]}, 
                       {c:[{v: new Date(2011,2,25,7,35,20),f:"03\/25\/2011 07:35am"}, {v:89.4,f:"89"} ]}, 
                       {c:[{v: new Date(2011,2,26,1,2,15),f:"03\/26\/2011 01:02am"}, {v:85.4,f:"85"} ]}, 
                       {c:[{v: new Date(2011,2,27,0,27,13),f:"03\/27\/2011 12:27am"}, {v:85.4,f:"85"} ]}] 
            },   0.6); 

       var annotatedtimeline = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
       annotatedtimeline.draw(data, {'displayAnnotations': true});
                                                                            }
            </script> 
          </head> 
        <body> 
        <div id='chart_div' style="width:400; height:250"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

To me this indicates that there must be one parsing step I'm missing. Like I said before, from all the troubleshooting I know how to do with the google code, I got that the row and col sizes were correct in the response from the database after calling the `var data = result.getDataTable()` function. So there must be one further modification I have to do to the variable data before I try to use it in my `annotatedtimeline.draw(data, {OPTIONS})` call.... Any ideas?

** ------------------------------------------------------------------------- **

**EDIT 2: NON WORKING CODE**
This is the non working code. The only real difference is the source of the data. And since I know that the database is responding, I am confused by the fact that its still showing a blank page.

```
 <html> 
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['annotatedtimeline']});
        function drawChart() {
         //Tell Google Visualization where your script is
                var query = new google.visualization.Query('/vis.php');
            query.setQuery('SELECT date,level FROM tank1 ORDER BY date');
            query.send(function(result) {
                //if there is an error
                document.write(result.getDetailedMessage());
                  if(result.isError()) {
                  alert(result.getDetailedMessage());

            } else {
                // otherwise plot the data
                var data = result.getDataTable();
                          // Inserting a document.write(data.getNumberOfRows()) proves that the datatable is loading seemingly correctly here
            var annotatedtimeline = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            annotatedtimeline.draw(data, { 'displayAnnotations': false });
                 }
               });
               }
           google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            </script> 
      </head> 
    <body> 
        <div id="chart_div" style="width:400px; height:250px"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this problem before, just fix this line in NON_WORKING_CODE

> `query.setQuery('SELECT date,level FROM tank1 ORDER BY date');`

into

> `query.setQuery('SELECT *');`

This should work. If not, try to fix the preg_quote issue https://code.google.com/p/mc-goog-visualization/issues/detail?id=16

Answer (score 1):

A look at the Google docmentation page here : http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html
Shows the following :

```
Important: To use this visualization, you must specify the height and width
           of the container element explicitly on your page. So, for example:
           <div id="chart_div" style="width:400; height:250"></div>.
```

You don't appear to do this.

EDIT : I just tried the example on that page and indeed if I remove the explicit height and width I get nothing; with the height and width the timeline displays.

Comment: Firstly, Hans, I appreciate your taking your time to help me! But after using this, I'm still getting a blank page. Originally I had it as one of the "chart.draw" options {width: 400, height: 300} but then I removed it thinking that constraint was my problem. however even when I test it again I still don't get anything displaying. I have tried firebug but it just shows me that my PHP script is running correctly. Any ideas where to troubleshoot the javascript to see the error? Any other techniques besides document.write, since I cant use that to parse the google datatable type?

Comment: Just to be clear have your tried replacing '<div id="chart_div"></div>' in your HTML with '<div id="chart_div" style="width:400; height:250"></div>'? If you confirm that with this change you still get a blank screen, I would try creating the chart from literal data instead of via an AJAX call. Its the divide and conquer approach : is your problem the AJAX part or the chart display part.

Comment: Great minds Hans :). I already did basically exactly that. I was able to take the EXACT data that I am returned from the SQL query, and fill it in into the google code playground and instead of the syntax data.addColumn('date','datetime') etc instead I used the json format: cols: [{id:'date',label: 'Date', type: 'datetime'}, etc.... And it worked! I was able to use the EXACT data that the SQL query returns from my PHP function verbatim and generate a plot with it... Then for completeness sake, I took the working code from the code playground and loaded it into my server. It also worked.

Comment: The other thing I tried was to take the variable data that the PHP SQL query returned and do a document.write(data.getNumberOfColumns()) and rows as well. This definitely returned the correct values (I'm using a rather small database, 30 rows, 2 cols, so its not that I'm overloading google with data here). So I know that the varaible is being created, I can see that it has the correct, name, type, value and I know the syntax works. But for some reason when I call annotatedtimeline.draw(), (or chart.draw(), depending on what I named my google.visualization of  course). I still get a blank page.

Comment: So you have working and non-working code versions. Did you take the next step, compare the working and non-working code and try cut and pastes to see what caused the problem to appear/disappear

Comment: Well not exactly and here is why: the "working" code, isnt pulling anything from my database. I know the PHP function that accesses the database is working, since I have seen its output and manually applied it in JSON form in JavaScript (in hard coded form), and that works. But  of course that isn't very useful beyond debugging. I will pull my results and post where I have gotten into my post above. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: There we go, I have added the working code at the bottom of my previous post. Anything jump out at you as a glaring difference between specifying the data table manually with the data, or dynamically pulling from my database?

Comment: OK I took your working code and as you say it displays a chart. Now I removed the  style="width:400; height:250" from the chart_div and now I get a blank screen. Which corresponds to my original answer at the top of this conversation. You have never explicitly said whether you have tried your non-working code with that style added. Your first comment alludes to that but without stating so explicitly. Try it now -- just add the style, nothing more or less, to the original question code above and tell me what happens.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I did try that as soon as you suggested it. I have added the non working code to the bottom of my post above. Its definitely somewhere in the `annotatedtimeline.draw` function that it stops working (at least apparently) since i am able to show that I got the JSON response the system was expecting from the PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

In your response, the keys are not enclosed in quote, it might be the reason why the chart is not rendered

```
{id:'date', type:'date'}

{"id":"date", "type":"date"}
```

I just searched for visualization.query documentation and [this](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#using_the_query_language) live example uses a response like yours but in the response, the keys are enclosed in quote:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7VFIQ&pub=1

I'm not familiarized with PHP and that visualization library you use in vis.php but if you could manage to add those quotes, I'm almost sure that it will work

I'm usign a tabledate with object notation as you did but in .NET and that's the only thing I see difference

Hope it helps, I know is an old post but for people like me in the future

Comment: Is this something that I can setup in my PHP code? I still have not gotten this working (not that I try very much, its a hobby project). In the "functional" code section above, I was able to specify the the id and type without quotes, and the JSON responded without including them either. Is there a specific fix to the code I have shown above that sticks out to you as a potential? Or something else I could show you to help elucidate some element of the process? i would just love some debugging information, since no errors are given, but nothing shows up.

Comment: I think that your `result.getDataTable()` is not returning an object but a string or null at some point, did you debug at this point of the code?, Also, Can you provide me some documentation of that php library for visualization? I'm pretty sure you must return the key enclosed in quote but I'm not familiarized with PHP or that library.